# How does Lunar Gateway compare to ISS and MIR

Tags: iss, the-moon, lunar-gateway

Looked around for comparison pictures, but can't find anyone (yet), probably because lunar gateway design is not yet stable. Or is it? I found several different designs.

Do they exist "blueprint" of LG, ISS, and possibly also MIR, to make a comparison?

--- edit ---

Orbital velocity provides a 3d paper model of a "minimal version" of Lunar Gateway, maybe usable to do some measurements:

[image: Orbital Velocity Lunar Gateway 3d paper model]

https://www.orbital-velocity.com/lunar-gateway-model

There are only Power Module (PPE), HALO module and Orion capsule.

I did some measurements:

- PPE: 25x25x31 mm ; panels: 58x197 mm
- HALO: 33 mm diameter, 16.5mm radius by 60mm length (plus a part around 10mm  - protruding from an edge)

Scale is 1:100, hence:

- PPE: 2.5x2.5x3.1 m; panels = 5.8 x 19.7 m
- HALO: 3.3m diameter by 7 meters length

Answer (score 5):

The design of the Gateway is still in flux, but here's an illustration from a couple of years ago showing it next to the ISS (lower right corner).

[image]

[Source](https://danielmarin.naukas.com/2018/06/27/la-plataforma-orbital-gateway-la-nueva-estacion-espacial-internacional-alrededor-de-la-luna/) (in Spanish)

This image compares Mir and ISS

[image]

[Source](https://historicspacecraft.com/ISS.html) Historic Spacecraft

Comment: `+1` I've just bumped [How many stages will likely be used to bring NASA astronauts to the Moon's south pole and safely back to Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35332/12102)

Comment: So - larger than Salyut but considerably smaller than Mir and Skylab.